# How to rewrite this method of getting a generic repository to use generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have this method to get a generic repository out of a dictionary:

```
public readonly IDictionary<Type, IRepository> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, IRepository>();

public IRepository GetRepository(Type type)
{
    if (this._repositories.ContainsKey(type)) {
        return this._repositories[type];
    }
    return null;
}
```

That works but I want it to work using generics so I tried:

```
public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    var typeParameterType = typeof(T);

     if (this._repositories.ContainsKey(typeParameterType)) {
         return this._repositories[typeParameterType];
     }
     return null;
}
```

But I get an error like 'Cannot implicitly convert type `IRepository` to `IRepository<T>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you'll need to either change `GetRepository`'s return type to the non-generic `IRepository`:

```
public IRepository GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    var typeParameterType = typeof(T);

    if (this._repositories.ContainsKey(typeParameterType)) 
        return this._repositories[typeParameterType];

    return null;
}
```

Or, simply cast the return of `this._repositories` to the generic type `IRepository<T>`:

```
public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    var typeParameterType = typeof(T);

    if (this._repositories.ContainsKey(typeParameterType)) 
        return this._repositories[typeParameterType] as IRepository<T>;

    return null;
}
```

Or possibly more appropriate:

```
public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    Repository<T> rep = null;

    this._repositories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out rep);

    return rep;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary have a type of IRepository. So when you withdraw an element, it also has this type. Your method on the other hand expects you to return value of the type `IRepository<T>`.

There are two ways to fix this. Either change your method's return type to IRepository, or convert the element to `IRepository<T>` before returning it:

```
return (IRepository<T>)this._repositories[typeParameterType];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type from `IRepository<T>` to simply `IRepository` to match the return type of your original non-generic method.

Answer (score 0):

the return type should be `IRepository` (note the lack of `<T>`) since IRepository isn't generic in the dictionary's definition.